# PHP PDO: When to properly end the connection

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO with a try...catch statement. I want to confirm with you guys if I understand this correctly. Do I put `$dbhandler = NULL` **before** the `throw`

```
$dbhandler = NULL;
if(!$sthandler->rowCount()) throw new invalidUplineException();
```

or **after** the throw

```
if(!$sthandler->rowCount()) throw new invalidUplineException();
$dbhandler = NULL;
```

Comment: PDO doesn't have an explicit close() or destructor call, so setting the handle to null is about the only thing you can do. Whether PDO will actually close the connection at that point or wait for some unspecified period of time/event is the real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a exception is thrown, the script execution jumps to the next matching `catch()` block (if you are inside a `try{}` block) or stops completely (if the exception is not caught). This behaviour is not related to PDO, it's how exceptions work in all languages that support them. Thus the `$dbhandler = NULL;` part in your second example will never be executed. Here's a simple test you can run:

```
<?php

try{
    throw new Exception('This exception will be caught');
    echo 'Exception thrown, this line will not run' . PHP_EOL;
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Exception was caught as expected' . PHP_EOL;
}

throw new Exception('This exception will not be caught. Script ends here.');
echo 'Exception thrown, this line will not run either.' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing a PDO connection is as simple as this:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // Make connection
$db = NULL; // Close connection
```

Comment: I know that. What I'm asking is whether it should be before or after the `throw...catch` statement.

Comment: But shouldn't $sthandler be $dbhandler btw?

Comment: That case you should close it after the throw, 'cause you're calling a method of $dbhandler.

Comment: no, it's really $sthandler. I'm using prepared statements so $sthandler holds the content.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of wrong using a reference which you have just set to `null`. So store the row count and after that set it to null:

```
$rowCount = $sthandler->rowCount();
$sthandler = null;
if(!$rowCount) {  throw new invalidUplineException(); }
```

"After the throw" could work but only in the cases where no exception was thrown.

Comment: I think this should be `$dbhandler = NULL;` instead of using $sthandler.